# Evaluating correctness of various definitions countable sets

Tags: sets

I was trying to understand the definition of countable set (again!!!). Wikipedia has a very great explanation:

> 1. A set $S$ is **countable** if there exists an $\color{red}{\text{injective}}$ function $f$ from $S$ to the natural numbers $\mathbb N$.
> 2. If such an $f$ can be found that is also surjective (and therefore $\color{red}{\text{bijective}}$), then $S$ is called **countably infinite**.
> 3. In other words, a set is **countably infinite** if it has $\color{red}{\text{bijection}}$ with the $\mathbb N$.

So I summarize:

1. $S$ is **countable** iff $S\xrightarrow{injection}\mathbb N$
2. $S$ is **countably infinite** iff $S\xrightarrow{bijection}\mathbb N$

But then wikipedia confuses by stating following points:

> **Theorem:** Let $S$ be a set. The following statements are equivalent:
>
> 1. $S$ is countable, i.e. there exists an injective function $f : S → \mathbb N$.
> 2. Either $S$ is empty or there exists a surjective function $g : \mathbb N → S$.
> 3. Either $S$ is finite or there exists a bijection $h : \mathbb N → S$.

**Q1.** I feel 2nd statement is wrong, as it allows some element in $S$ to not to map to any element in $\mathbb N$. That is $\mathbb N \xrightarrow{surjection} S$ does not imply $S\xrightarrow{injection}\mathbb N$. Hence $S$ is not countable. Right?
**Q2.** 3rd  statement defines countably infinite set, so its countable also. Right?
**Q3.** Also I dont get if the extra restrictions of emptyness and finiteness in statements 2 and 3 are required.

Wikipedia further says:

> **Corollary:** Let $S$ and $T$ be sets.
>
> 1. If the function $f : S → T$ is injective and $T$ is countable then $S$ is countable.
> 2. If the function $g : S → T$ is surjective and $S$ is countable then $T$ is countable.

**Q4.** Here, too, I feel 2nd statement is incorrect for the same reason as 2nd statement in the theorem. Right?

Comment: This seems like a math question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wikipedia theorem is correct. More generally, if $A$ is an ordered set and there exists a surjection $g\colon A \twoheadrightarrow B$ then there exists an injection $f\colon B \hookrightarrow A$ given by $f(b) = \min g^{-1}(b)$. This is an injection since $g(f(b)) = b$.

More generally, if you assume the axiom of choice then you don't need to assume that $A$ is ordered, since the axiom of choice guarantees the existence of a function $f\colon B \to A$ satisfying $f(b) \in g^{-1}(b)$ for all $b \in B$.

Comment: So does that means element of countable set $S$ is allowed to map to more than one natural numbers? Will be a bit surprised to know yes. It seems that both (based on surjection and injection) definitions allow it. Like in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Surjection.svg) figure, there is $X \xrightarrow{surjection} Y$ and hence $X \xrightarrow{inection} Y$ and $C$ maps to 3 and 4. So such mapping is allowed from countable set to $\mathbb N$?

Comment: A function maps every element of its domain to a unique element in its range.